# What is the color score in the fruit_data examples used in Machine Learning tutorials?

Tags: machine-learning

[image]

Quite a few tutorials using this fruit data example. What is the color score? How is it calculated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found from the course "Applied Machine Learning in Python".

[image]

There is a "complicated way" to calculate the score. But here is the simplistic version.